# request close index is not allowed by Amazon Elasticsearch Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch

I can not close the index on Amazon OpenSearch Service

I'm using `Amazon OpenSearch Service` with `elasticsearch` version is `6.3` and `6.8`.
I want to update the `setting` to add an `analyzer`.
I have read the docs. I need to close the `index` and update setting and then open `index` again.
When I'm trying to close the index, I got this error:

```
{"Message":"Your request: '/my_index/_close' is not allowed by Amazon Elasticsearch Service."}
```

How can I update my setting?
Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to use `_close` API on AWS managed ES lower than 7.4. You can check the [official troubleshooting guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/handling-errors.html#aes-troubleshooting-close-api) about it.

1. To use `_close` API, you have to upgrade your elasticsearch to version 7.4 or greater. There are a lot of deprecation settings between version 6 and 7. Please check the deprecation settings before upgrade ES.
2. Another method is creating a new index with custom analyzer and reindexing data into that index.

> OpenSearch Service supports the _close API only for OpenSearch and
> Elasticsearch versions 7.4 and later. If you're using an older version
> and are restoring an index from a snapshot, you can delete the
> existing index (before or after reindexing it).

Comment: Yes, I have researched a lot and got the same result. 
I'm trying another solution. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Lee, please let me know the result.